# Open a crosstab query in a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access document with a main form and a subform inside it. I have to write some code in the way so every other form will open inside that subform. Now my problem is that I have a crosstab query that its column count is different each time run. How can I open it in the subform?
Thanks

Comment: Can set subform container control SourceObject to the query. Of course, disadvantage is can't have code behind subform. Building a stable CROSSTAB that can be used as data source for forms and reports is possible but tricky. Fairly common topic. Start with https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/crosstab-report/index.html

Comment: Thanks June7. Unfortunately I cant set sub_form SourceObject to a query in vba. It faces error. Also I made a form to show cross_tab  query results and tried to create some empty textboxes and labels and set their control source and caption to query header. but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think the cross tab query or anything else actually has to "fit" the sub form. Access will display what it can.Users can even adjust the width of columns to see what they need to see. A customer showed me this!

Comment: Using VBA to set SourceObject to query worked for me. `Forms("Main").ctrTeams.SourceObject = "Query.Ribbons"`. Edit your question to show attempted code.